# Connect to docker container from the host

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

I have several docker containers running on my local machine.  One with SQL Server, one with RabbitMQ, and one with my code.  Everything works fine within the docker containers but how can I reference these containers from outside?

I would like to connect to SQL Server with the management studio installed on my desktop.  I would also like to hit the RabbitMQ management console from the browser on my desktop.

Inside the container I reference the other containers with a hostname but this is not visible outside of the network.  I can connect with the IP but that changes each time I start it.

Is there a way to give each container a hostname that is visible from the host?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: You can publish container port https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: your localhost is able to parse the container name to its ip, therefore all you have to do is to publish a port in the container and send there your traffic.